# Can electric fields of multipoles just be described in terms of monopoles, if so then why do we have to do multipole expansion instead of monopoles?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, potential, voltage, multipole-expansion

Can we describe the most complex electric field just using monopoles rather than going into multipoles expansion, because using superposition principle we can tell the potential of entire system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The multipole expansion is an asymptotic expansion of the far field created by a charge distribution.

Say that the charge distribution $\rho$ is contained in a ball of radius $r$ then you use the multipole expansion for calculating the field or potential at distances $R \gg r$.

Generally the solution to the Poisson equation for the potential in electrostatics is the convolution between the charge distribution and the fundamental solution of the Poisson equation, which you can understand as an infinite superposition of point-charge potentials. But this can be complicated and not always easily computed. If the approximate far-field description is enough, then what we gain from using the multipole expansion is a great deal of simplicity.

And yes, technically you can describe multipole fields in terms of monopoles. Say, for example, that the leading term in a multipole expansion is the dipole term. Instead of the potential or field created by an ideal dipole (which has a charge distribution containing $\nabla \delta$) you can replace it by the potential or field created by a real dipole: two opposite charges a certain distance $\ell$ apart (with charges and distance chosen such that we have the same dipole moment). As long as $\ell \ll r \ll R$ we won't be able to tell the difference in the far-field approximation. But we have lost some of the simplicity: There is an additional, superfluous variable $\ell$. As long as $\ell$ is small enough, its value doesn't matter, so better take $\ell \rightarrow 0$, which yields the ideal dipole.